# method won't fully execute before moving to the next

Tags: c#, uwp

So i have an apiService that gets trips from my database

```
public class ApiService
{
    public ObservableCollection<Trip> Trips;
    
    public ApiService()
    {
        Trips = new ObservableCollection<Trip>();
    }
    public async void LoadTripsAsync()
    {
        
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var json = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:49875/api/Trip/"));
        var tripList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Trip>>(json);
        foreach(var trip in tripList)
        {
            trip.DestinationImage = "Assets/Berlijn.jpg";
            Trips.Add(trip);
        }
        
    }
    
    

}
```

and in my homepageviewmodel, i try to display the first upcoming trip:

```
public class HomePageViewmodel
{
    
    
    public Trip FirstTrip { get; set; }
    private ApiService _service;
    public HomePageViewmodel()
    {
        _service = new ApiService();
        SetFirstTrip();
        
    }
    public void SetFirstTrip()
    { 
            _service.LoadTripsAsync();
            
            FirstTrip = _service.Trips.OrderBy(t => t.StartDate).FirstOrDefault();
    }

}
```

the problem is that the ObservableCollection "Trips" in my APIservice is always empty. There are definity Trips in the database because i use the exact Api method somewhere else which works perfect.

When i debug, i find some very strange behaviour. Ill try my best to explain it like this:

so first it goes here:

```
_service.LoadTripsAsync();
```

then, as you would expect, it goes to my apiservice and runs until i hit this line:

```
var json = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:49875/api/Trip/"));
```

i then expect the rest of the method to run, so it can fill the ObservableCollection "trips" but instead it goes back to my viewmodel to run this:

```
 FirstTrip = _service.Trips.OrderBy(t => t.StartDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

ofcourse, _service.Trips is still empty.

How do I make it so that it completes my api method first, before executing the rest?

Comment: `LoadTripsAsync` is async; You need to `await` it.

Comment: ...except you can't since its return type is `void`. Change it to `Task`.

Comment: As a general rule, [avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

Answer (score 2):

`LoadTripsAsync` is async so you have to await it:

```
public class HomePageViewmodel
{
    public Trip FirstTrip { get; set; }
    private ApiService _service;

    public HomePageViewmodel()
    {
        _service = new ApiService();
        SetFirstTripAsync();
    }

    public async void SetFirstTripAsync()
    { 
       await _service.LoadTripsAsync();  
       FirstTrip = _service.Trips.OrderBy(t => t.StartDate).FirstOrDefault();
    }

}
```

Comment: i did that and changed the apiService method to a task, unfortunatly, it now only works when i debug, not when i just run the app

Comment: i also had to add Task.Run(() => this.SetFirstTripAsync()).Wait(); in the constructor of my homepageview, it now fully works